# accordion issue to open first one automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want that the first  tab  should expand automatically mean when i refresh my page the first tab should expand like 
General (top header)(-)
lorem ipsum (-)
lorem ipsum doller amu site amu doller

lorem ipsum (+)
lorem ipsum (+)
lorem ipsum (+)
lorem ipsum (+)

......please any one can help....

script is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //Initialising Accordion
            $(".accordion").tabs(".pane", {
                tabs: '> h2',
                effect: 'slide',
                initialIndex: null
            });

            //The click to hide function
            $(".accordion > h2").click(function() {
                if ($(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
                    $(this).next().slideUp();
                    $(this).removeClass("current");
                } else if (!$(this).hasClass("current") && $(this).next().queue().length === 0) {
                    $(this).next().slideDown();
                    $(this).addClass("current");
                }
            });
        });
```

and html is

```
 <div class="accordion">
        <h2 style="background-color: #007194; text-align: center;   padding: 0;font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: normal;"><span style="font-size: 40px;"></span><?php echo "$value";?> <span> FAQS </span></h2>

       <div class="pane">
            <div class="accordion">
        <?php 

           while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))    
            {
                echo "<h2> ".$row['question']."</h2>";
                echo "<div class='pane'><div class='accordion'><p>".$row['answer']."</p></div></div>";

            }
      ?>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this jQuery UI you are using? You realize there is an `.accordion()` UI feature as well as `.tabs()` right?  Also, those options you are passing into `tabs()` don't reflect modern jQ UI option set - what version(s) of jQuery and UI are you using?

Comment: jQuery UI's `.accordion()` automatically behaves how you describe (with the first tab open on page load) so why are you not using that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [JQuery Accordion](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) and his `active` option,like in this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({active: 0);
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="accordion">
      <h3>First header</h3>
      <div>First content panel</div>
      <h3>Second header</h3>
      <div>Second content panel</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that even if I explicitely added `active` option set to 0, this is the default value.

In your case you should write
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            //Initialising Accordion
            $("#accordion").accordion()
            });
```

HTML

```
 <div class="accordion">
        <h2 style="background-color: #007194; text-align: center;   padding: 0;font-family: 'Raleway',sans-serif;text-transform: uppercase;font-weight: normal;"><span style="font-size: 40px;"></span><?php echo "$value";?> <span> FAQS </span></h2>

       <div class="pane">
            <div id="accordion">
        <?php 

           while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret))    
            {
                echo "<h3> ".$row['question']."</h3>";
                echo "<div class='pane'><div class='accordion'><p>".$row['answer']."</p></div></div>";

            }
      ?>

        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

H3 is used here because is JQuery default, but you can change it in the options.

Also remember that the accordion is applied on the first level of div after the h3 tag, so the div with the pane class in your case.

Comment: +1 for the only right answer so far. the `active` option already defaults to `0` - the first accordion pane is open by default.  if he wanted them closed or set to a different index he could specify the option (either `false` to close or `X` index) but otherwise the call need simply be `$('#accordion').accordion();`

Comment: If I've understood correctly please wait some minutes, time to write it

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".accordian").first().addClass("current");
```

Comment: where should i place this one?

Comment: Immediately after you initialize the accordion.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be found here:

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

The jquery UI accordian widget seems to do what you want, and when it loads on the page the first one is set to be open automatically

Also the collapsible set from jquery mobile is easy to set a specific one to collapsed or expanded and still have accordian like features

http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/collapsibleset/

Answer (score 0):

For the first block to active, use this approach :

```
<div class="active">

<a href="#">This is questions...</a>

<div style="display: block">
     <p>This is answer....</p>  
 </div>

</div>
```

in your case, use increment no++ and use if $no == 1, put the above script. Else remove class active and display: block